# Unix Diff command compare difference between 2 txt files and generate more command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, diff

I have created a script, which will generate a list of IPs and then put them in the name of "ip-$date.txt". for example, ip-20130619.txt. Tomorrow it will be ip-20130620.txt

Now I need to create another script, which will compare the latest ip-$date file with the older file, and do two things:
1. The IPs that are not in an older date file, I need to generate a list
2. The IPs that are in the older date file, but no longer in the newer date file, I need to generate another list.

I have been trying to use the Diff command, but somehow I don't think it can differentiate with the two scenarios above. Only return the merge, can't tell which one is which.

Can you experts give me a few pointers?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
comm <(sort oldfile) <(sort newfile)
```

(or if the files are already sorted, simply `comm oldfile newfile`). This will show lines that are only in `oldfile` in the first column, only in `newfile` in the second column, and common to both in the third column. Since you don't seem to care about the third column, you could change that to `comm -3 ....` to omit that column. If you don't want to parse the output by column, you can do `comm -23 ....` to get the first column only, and `comm -13 ....` to get the second only, but that obviously takes two invocations...

Comment: how can I compare the dates though? how can the script auto recognize that a file has a newer date?

Comment: Probably by using something like `date -d "2 days ago" +%Y%m%d` and `date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d`. Capture those values in variables and use them to construct the file names... Of course the benefit in the YYYYMMDD order is that, if you strip off the prefix/suffix, the dates sort naturally in numeric order...

Comment: I guess my question is not clear.... How can I only run the comm against the 2 most recent files?

Comment: solved... Just remove it by ls -t1|tail -n +3|xargs rm -r